# What is the correct way to update meta fields in Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've just upgraded to WooCommerce 3.0 and am trying to get my plugin working.

I've noticed that when I update a custom field against an Order using update_post_meta, it doesn't update the cache.

When I then create a new `WC_Order` and run the method `update_status`, it uses the previous value against the field that I previously updated.

With the new version of Woocommerce, what is the correct way to update meta fields against an order?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: I think you have to call `wc_delete_shop_order_transients( $order );` after you call your update...

Comment: I saw that in another private function that ran 2 other cache related functions (WordPress functions, not woo). I tried it and it did work but I'm not sure exactly what this does. I thought there might be a better way to create the records that keeps the cache in sync.